# Replacement for Web Services Core?

Tags: web-services, cocoa, xml-rpc

It seems that back in OS X 10.8, Apple deprecated all of Web Services Core.  Is there a replacement, preferably drop-in?  In particular, I'm dealing with XML-RPC, so coupling `NSURL*` with `NSXMLParser` or some such is nowhere near as convenient as using `WSMethodInvocationRef`.